# 3D Revolve, but spaced out in a segment style in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I'm trying to revolve a 2D shape so that the final 3D shape has a segmented style. See below:

[image]

http://img.alexblundell.com/up/c5693a8d4351fd0c498c8919a2a3e43b.png

I'm sure there's an automated way to do this, but I haven't yet found how. Anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

There's really no easy way to accomplish this with Illustrator.

One thing is for certain, the 3D Effect won't do it.

You can try a blend with various steps predefined for the blend.

Quick crude example:

[image]

Comment: I think Scott has the right idea.  

1. Create your base shape.  

2. Scale it for the other extreme.  

3. Blend the two and adjust the steps until you're happy.  

4. Use an x-axis flip to mirror the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did in CS3:

1. Draw a curve with the pen tool.
2. Go to **Effect > 3D > Revolve**
3. X axis(red) = 0, Y axis (green) = -180, rotation (blue) = 0
4. Click **OK**

My version isn't pretty, but with a few tweaks you can get it to what you need.
I don't have enough rep to post the screenshots I took for you, but I think this should get you started.

Comment: The restriction on posting images is a big pain... one way to work around it where the image is an important part of the question or answer is to upload the image to something like imgur directly then post a link to it.